# why does perf record and annotate not work?

Tags: linux, performance, x86, perf

I'm stumped, I read the perf tutorial and am trying to do a simple test beyond "perf stat" which works. However perf record either doesnt work ,or perf annotate shows no samples recorded. Running perf

For example(im running with sudo because without it i get a bunch of errors which i will post at the end):

`sudo perf record -e cycles,instructions,cache-misses -a -c 1 ./FooExe`

```
[ perf record: Woken up 4 times to write data ]
[ perf record: Captured and wrote 1.794 MB perf.data (~78393 samples) ]
```

.

```
sudo perf report -D -i perf.data |grep RECORD_SAMPLE |wc -l
Failed to open /tmp/perf-23796.map, continuing without symbols
20486
```

.

`sudo perf annotate -d ./FooExe`

`the perf.data file has no samples!   Press any key`

So thats as far as i get.  I tried to rebuild perf for my ssystem from source but that didnt seem to help either.

Im using Ubuntu 14.04 kernel 3.19.0-49-generic.  This is on intel i7 I4510U cpu . I made sure to compile my program with symbols , but i get the same results regardless of which application i try to profile.

-- if i run without sudo :

```
WARNING: Kernel address maps (/proc/{kallsyms,modules}) are restricted,
check /proc/sys/kernel/kptr_restrict.

Samples in kernel functions may not be resolved if a suitable vmlinux
file is not found in the buildid cache or in the vmlinux path.

Samples in kernel modules won't be resolved at all.

If some relocation was applied (e.g. kexec) symbols may be misresolved
even with a suitable vmlinux or kallsyms file.

Cannot read kernel map
Error:
You may not have permission to collect system-wide stats.
Consider tweaking /proc/sys/kernel/perf_event_paranoid:
 -1 - Not paranoid at all
  0 - Disallow raw tracepoint access for unpriv
  1 - Disallow cpu events for unpriv
  2 - Disallow kernel profiling for unpriv
```

Comment: I might post a bigger answer later, but you don't need `sudo`.  `perf` tries to include CPU time spent in kernel mode inside system calls.  If you're only trying to profile what your code does in user-space, the warning message is harmless.  Profiling still works.  Is `perf report` failing because the sample data is owned by root and unreadable?  Try removing any root-owned files and starting again without using sudo at all.

Comment: ok thanks.  I tried removing the sudo owned data and repeating the test.  When I do so if i try perf annotate -d ./FooExe then perf starts up shows a progress bar and immediately quits.  If i try without the -d option it simply shows "perf.data file has no samples"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just tried your command.  The problem was that you used `-a` to profile all processes system-wide, so it never ran `./FooExe`.  You can confirm this with `strace -f  perf ... ./FooExe`, and note the lack of any `execve` system call.  And also the fact that it returns instantly, even if FooExe should have taken several seconds.

Here's an example of recording samples for a busy-loop awk command:

```
perf record -e cycles,instructions,cache-misses awk 'BEGIN{for(i=0;i<40000000;i++){}}'
```

Now `perf report` works.  You don't need to specify the executable for the `report` command, because `perf.data` only has data for the one executable.

---

This works the same way with [the `ocperf.py` wrapper](http://halobates.de/blog/p/245), but you could record events for more uarch-specific events using symbolic names (instead of looking up codes and numeric arguments in `-e`):

```
$ ocperf.py record -e cycles,cache-misses,uops_dispatched_port.port_0 awk 'BEGIN{for(i=0;i<40000000;i++){}}'
perf record -e cycles,cache-misses,cpu/event=0xa1,umask=0x1,name=uops_dispatched_port_port_0,period=2000003/ awk 'BEGIN{for(i=0;i<40000000;i++){}}'
  (warning lines about kernel symbols)
[ perf record: Woken up 2 times to write data ]
[ perf record: Captured and wrote 0.352 MB perf.data (7819 samples) 
$ ocperf.py report
```

Comment: thanks , no idea why but i could have sworn i tried that before (without the system wide flag ) but anyway it does seem to work now as you said.  Cheers

Comment: ok now I have another problem - I get output that doesnt show me actual symbols :for example  ocperf.py record --call-graph dwarf  -e misalign_mem_ref.stores -c 1 ./a.out    , then ocperf.py report -g graph --no-children , shows me 40% a.out [unknown] [k] 0xffffffff813b4578.  I made sure to compile with -fno-omit-frame-pointer

Comment: @skimon: Did you compile with `-g` for full debug symbols, too?  Are you sure you need `-fno-omit-frame-pointer`?  stack-unwinding works without it (thanks to the `.eh_frame_hdr` section, IIRC).  It would only need to do this if you have it recording a backtrace at every sample to see whether calls from some parents are more expensive than others.  IDK if it even does this; I've mostly messed around with isolating a loop I'm tuning and looking at `perf stat` output.  I haven't actually done a lot of record/annotate.  I think normally it just samples the instruction pointer.

Comment: i did compile with -g , someone elso on SO had a q&a suggesting that perf couldnt understand dwarf format debug symbols so i tried to use the appropriate recording options (i forget now but something like -g dwarf ).  Anyway no dice on that.  Another suggestion from SO was the frame pointer option.  Symbols from std library fpr example seem to show up, just nothing from my code itself. Thanks for the help, worst case i may start a new question.